# Is there a way of setting a range when querying data of firestore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have a collection of documents, all with random id's and a field called `date`.

```
docs = collection_ref.order_by(u'date', direction=firestore.Query.ASCENDING).get()
```

Imagine I had limited the search to the first ten

```
docs = collection_ref.order_by(date', direction=firestore.Query.ASCENDING).limit(10).get()
```

How would I continue with my next query when I want to get the items from 11 to 20?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use an `offset()`,but every doc skipped counts as a read. For example, if you did `query.offset(10).limit(5)`, you would get charged for 15 reads: the 10 offset + the 5 that you actually got.

If you want to avoid unnecessary reads, use `startAt()` or `startAfter()`

example (Java, sorry, don't speak python. [here's link to docs though](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query)):

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = // your query snapshot

List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = querySnapshot.getDocuments();

//reference doc, query starts at or after this one
DocumentSnapshot indexDocSnapshot = docs.get(docs.size());

//to 'start after', or paginate, you can do below:
query.startAfter(indexDocSnapshot).limit(10).get()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                                // next 10 docs here, no extra reads necessary
                            });
```

Comment: Hello Shmibbles, in your java example, and the premise "offset 10 and limit 5", where did you indicate the limit 5 and the offset?